# How to make a counter in TextView in DialogFragment?

Tags: android, counter, textview

I have a problem making DialogFragment that holds a counter (like counts incoming files For example 0/50 50/50). The problem is with updating TextView to show count of files that are coming. 
Can you please help me with this? 
Thank you!

`public class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {`

```
    public static ProgressDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
    ProgressDialogFragment frag = new ProgressDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

private View view;
private String title;
public TextView textViewLoading;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_dialog_layout, container);

    textViewLoading = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_loading);

    return view;
}

public void updateCount(int position, int size) {
    textViewLoading.setText(title + " " + position + "/" + size);
}`
```

Then instantiate this class:

`ProgressDialogFragment dialogProgressLoading = ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance("load challenges");
            dialogProgressLoading.show(manager, "tag");`

And try to update the count:

```
   `dialogProgressLoading.updateCount(position, values.size());`
```

Its not working. I try to update a counter from adapter

Comment: where from files are coming? also share what you have tried until now

Comment: please take a look at the code above. I added a code

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: no error. counter is not working like it should (not updating its values)

Answer (score 0):

```
 private int count = 0;
 private TextView fileCounterText;



 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 fileCounterText = (TextView) findViewbyId(R.id.textviewsXMLid);

for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
 {
    //file code
    count++;
    fileCounterText.setText("count");
  }
```

Comment: this code will give you an idea of what you have to do, I don't know the details of your code so this is all I can give you. Play around with this for loop.

Comment: That's not a problem, I asked about FragmentDialog. Making counter in fragment is quite a problem. I'm thinking about ViewAnimator to make it but I'm not sure